# Sentence case or proper case in a TextBox

Tags: .net, vb.net, textbox

I want my `TextBox` to make the text I enter as `Sentence Case(ProperCase)`.. but I don't want to write any code in an event like `Lost Focus` or `KeyPress`.

Just by default, whenever a user enters or types in a textbox the first letter of every word should automatically be converted into `UpperCase`.

Comment: I may be wrong, but I think the only way to do this is to check the value of the textbox as the text is entered using an event and update the text accordingly.

Comment: I have tried by using Culture Class but i think that will be heavy on processing..

Comment: You are dealing with user input.  You've got 100 million cpu cycles to get the job done before the user will notice.

Comment: Thanks for this question - I voted this up because I would have had no clue given the answer

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I don't know of a way to do this in WinForms without putting some code in an event. The `CharacterCasing` property of a TextBox allows you to force all characters entered to upper or lower case, but not to do Proper Casing. Incidentally, it's a single line of code to do it in an event:

```
TextBox1.Text = StrConv(TextBox1.Text, VbStrConv.ProperCase)
```

A more generic handler for doing this across multiple textboxes involves attaching a number of events to the same code:

```
'Attach multiple events to this handler
Private Sub MakeProperCase(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles _
    TextBox1.LostFocus, TextBox2.LostFocus, TextBox3.LostFocus

    'Get the caller of the method and cast it to a generic textbox
    Dim currentTextBox As TextBox = DirectCast(sender, TextBox)
    'Set the text of the generic textbox to Proper Case
    currentTextBox.Text = StrConv(currentTextBox.Text, VbStrConv.ProperCase)

End Sub
```

In ASP.NET, you *can* do this [without code](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_text-transform.asp); there's a CSS property called `text-transform`, one of the values for this property is `capitalize`. When applied to a text input element, it makes the first letter of each word uppercase.

Answer (score 0):

This case there are two controls: cboDestination and txtUser. It make what you want while you type letters.

```
Private Sub properCase_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) _ 
        Handles cboDestination.TextChanged, txtUser.TextChanged
        Dim n As Integer = sender.SelectionStart
        sender.Text = StrConv(sender.Text, VbStrConv.ProperCase)
        sender.SelectionStart = n
End Sub
```